# installing pytorch on the pi

Tags: software-installation

I am extensively using [torch](https://pytorch.org) on a desktop CPU and would like to use it on the pi. I have found https://pitorch.org/, but it's still in construction (nice name, guys!) - is there any experience on installing it on the pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `sudo pip install pytorch` (for Python2) or `sudo pip3 install pytorch` (for Python3) should install it from https://pypi.org/project/pytorch/ automagically.

Comment: Looks like a dummy package to me...

Comment: @dirk the instructions are https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ are in pure 100% gobbledegook, I'm not sure how or what you're supposed to install for this. The only clear statement is python3 not python2. The OP probably needs to contact the developer.